# Show Pictures in RDLC report using Dataset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, report, rdlc

I have one rdlc report with many sub reports.
one of the sub reports showing images stored in application.

Actual images are stored in application folder like "~/Images/Photos" and database column file has only name like picture1.jpg

here is my sub report scree shot
[image]

and here is my code

[image]

but this is giving me output like this

[image]

**Update**

output of my linq query is
[image]

all the images are different so why it is repeating.

Comment: what is the o/p of the query in sql?

Comment: see updated question

Comment: what is the value of filepath for [1] and [2]? for [0] it is tulip-xxxx

Comment: i have updated an image... please take a look

Comment: What does the expression for picture box look like in the report itself? Is it First(...) by chance?

Comment: can u show the expression or sql query in SSRS?

Comment: @AijazChauhan i think that is the issue here..can u post the steps u followed

Comment: @Sachu all steps are written above..but in image properties Image source="External" and in use this image i have used =First(Fields!FilePath.Value, "PreSurveyPhotosDataset")

Answer (score 0):

it is not the issue with your dataset
it is because of the expression u put in SSRS image properties

you put

```
 Image source="External" and =First(Fields!FilePath.Value, "PreSurveyPhotosDataset")
```

because of `First()` it will always show the first one. Remove `First()` and try